# csrf error when using body-parser on sails

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm trying to use formidable and body-parser for post request and everything is working but when I enabled csrf I'm always getting `forbidden` maybe because body-parser is not handling multipart anymore. How can I make csrf work using body-parser and formidable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the source code for `csurf`, but I am pretty sure the middleware uses `req.param('_csrf')` to check for the csrf token. Therefore, just append `?_csrf=<token>` to your post URL.